# material ui create and position badge element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

This is my first time using material ui and and I want to create colored rounded squares with a letter inside positioned on a card component like the image below .

[image]

As you can see the colored square with "A" sits like a badge on the card component . I want to implement the same thing on my cards using material ui but I do not know where to find this feature .
This is how my card looks like :

[image]

My code to display a component :

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import  CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import VisibilityIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';


const useStyles = makeStyles({
  cardRoot: {
    width:"400px",
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    fontWeight:"bold",
    lineHeight:"1.5rem",
    marginLeft:"50px",
    padding:"10px"
  },
  bullet: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    margin: '0 2px',
    transform: 'scale(0.8)',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    fontWeight:"bold",
    lineHeight:"1.5rem",
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  badge:{
    height:"100px",
    width:"120px",
    borderRadius:"10px"
  },
  viewContainer:{
    top:"-30px",
    left:"26px",
    position:"relative",
    padding:"10px",
    cursor:"pointer",
    width:"fit-content",
    float:"right",
    '&>*':{
      marginLeft:"5px",
      fontSize: "1.1rem",
      lineHeight: "1.25rem",
      color:"crimson",
    },
    '&:hover':{
      backgroundColor:"whitesmoke"
    }
  },


});




export default function Job({job}) {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;
  return (
    <Grid item sm = {4} xs = {2}>
      <Card className= {classes.cardRoot}>
        <CardContent>
          <Box p = {1} display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end" flexDirection="row" className={classes.viewContainer}>
            <VisibilityIcon></VisibilityIcon>
            <Typography component = "span"> VIEW DETAILS</Typography> 
          </Box>
          <Box display ="flex" justifyContent="flex-start">
            <Box p ={1}>
              <Typography style = {{color: "#6e8098"}}> 0d ago   </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box p = {1}>
              <Typography style = {{color: "#6e8098"}}> {bull} {job.type} </Typography>
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <Box display= "flex" justifyContent = "flex-start" alignItems="flex-start" flexDirection="column">
            <Box p={1}>
              <Typography variant = "h2" component = "h2" className= {classes.title}>
                {job.title}
              </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box p ={1}>
              <Typography style = {{color: "#6e8098"}}>{job.company}</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box p={1}>
              <Typography color="secondary" >{job.location}</Typography>
            </Box>
          </Box>
          
        </CardContent>
        
      </Card> 
          
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

I would appreciate your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround your `Card` component in the `Badge` component to makes it work. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-zhukovsky-u93zr?file=/src/App.js)

```
<Badge color="secondary" badgeContent={99}>
        <Card className={classes.cardRoot}>
```

Comment: This does not help a lot with my current code . By ovveriding the badge the card style also ovverides .Thank you still

Comment: You shouldn't override the card. If you look at the sandbox link, I just assigned badge style class to the badge component and the card component remains intact.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a look around the Avatar component.

[avatar Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALK2V.png)

You can easily use it like:

```
 <Avatar src={member.name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()} />
```

and just override the rounded theming with your square one.

Hope that have help you have a great day.